# $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{1+1/x}-x-\log x$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{1+1/x}-x}{\log x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, contest-math

Evaluate 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{1+1/x}-x-\log x$$ 
and 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{1+1/x}-x}{\log x}$$
Would knowing one necessarily give the other?

Comment: "contest-math" What contest?

Comment: I think it is putnam contest problem

Comment: it's inspired from a problem in VTRMC

Comment: What problem in VTRMC? What is VTRMC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x(x^{1/x}-1) = x(e^{\frac{1}{x}\log(x)} -1) = x(\dfrac{\log x}{x} + O(\dfrac{(\log x)^2}{x^2})) = \log x + O(\dfrac{(\log x)^2}{x})$